# Not able to activate trigger send in sales cloud using cloud connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a trigger send on the lead object using marketing cloud connect but when I am activating the trigger it is giving me alert,

> Before activating a triggered send the appropriate Apex Trigger must be created for the following object: LEAD. Please refer to Marketing Cloud Help for more information.

For that, I have added a trigger,

```
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
    et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Lead');
}
```

after this also I am still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was really annoying to make it running. 
It seems like the connector checks for the same naming convention which is provided in the documentation. My problem was, we have one trigger per sObject so the code was recognised in our trigger template.

At the end, I had to deploy a separate trigger only for that propose. Below is the is the code.

```
trigger Trig_Lead on Lead (after insert, after update)
{
    if (!Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Lead');
    }
}
```

Also, the trigger needs to have a code coverage which also doesn't make sense when you by pass the deployment with a condition (!Test.isRunningTest()). But it was the only way and after the deployment I had to run the test class which then give me a code coverage of 50%. Finally, I was able to activate it.

Maybe the connector version might be important as well, my current version was (210.1.1)

Wish you good luck.

Best
Yoonsang